# swift UIButton highlighted image not firing on first click

Tags: swift, uibutton

So simple code - when button is pressed, change the background image to something else.

```
    func betMaxButtonPressed (button: UIButton) {
    print("bet max button pressed")
    self.betMaxButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "betMaxHighlighted"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

}
```

This function is called in another function (set up containerView) which in turn is called in viewDidLoad.

It works BUT not on first press, subsequent presses do. If I add the code

```
self.betMaxButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "betMaxHighlighted"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

to viewDidLoad then all is good and fires on 1st click. Just trying to figure out why this is.

Comment: I guess because this method is called when press is done. Why just not set this before this button will be pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to change the image each time you press, setting an image for a `UIControlState` is something that follows that button. So what you want to do is in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.betMaxButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "betMaxNormal"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.betMaxButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "betMaxHighlighted"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

This sets up which image should be shown for which state. So when the button is pressed it will change the image automatically. No need to set the image in the outlet method.

Comment: Many thanks. That works. Dudi comment also makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 func betMaxButtonPressed (button: UIButton) {
    print("bet max button pressed")
    self.betMaxButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "betMaxHighlighted"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

Note: If you want unhighlight then you need to change button bg(normal Image)

Comment: Thanks for that. Kinda works but I only want the new image (its the same image but diff colour = like a highlight) to highlight when touchUpInside fires. Then needs to go back to normal image. Is there a cleaner way to do it?